# Problems with 3D vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++, and I am having a bit of problem with this 3D vector I am trying to work with. The core of the problem is the following code. I create a 100*100*10 3D vector, but inside my main function the program doesn't seem to know it exists since I'm getting an error when I try to run it. "Error: Symbol particleGrid is not defined in current scope". 2D vectors does not have this problem. I am running the code with ROOT, if that is of importance.

```
using namespace std;
Int_t gridResolution=100;
vector<vector<vector<int>>> particleGrid(gridResolution,vector<vector<int>>(gridResolution,vector<int>(10)));

void main(){
    particleGrid.clear();
}
```

Any help or hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried 1D vector, with #include <vector>, compiling was OK.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  As [demonstrated here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/pyKtj$3), the above code can be easily made to compile.  Your compiler is clearly not standards compliant, because `main` cannot return `void` in C++.

Comment: It seems that he/she is using ROOT

Comment: ROOT?  Ah, hadn't heard of that one.

Comment: me neither. I just googled `is not defined in current scope` and found `ROOT`. I am not sure what `ROOT` exactly is. Perhaps, it's a library + interpreter.

Comment: Looks like ROOT uses/is a C++ interpreter(!?) in a scientific computation context.  Some advice to the OP: do lots of `typedef`s to simplify your types.  I'd avoid putting `>`s in "actual code", instead `typedef` such types.  `typedef vector<int> vec1d; typedef vector<vec1d> vec2d; typedef vector<vec2d> vec3d;`.  As a second bit of advice, `vector`s-of-`vector`s-of-`vector`s is not always optimal -- many people build a flat array with manual index management rather than stack vectors, if the various dimensions don't change regularly.

Comment: @Yakk I personally prefer `int[n][m][o]` over a flat array. Anyway, both will work. It's just syntactically different.

Comment: Yes, but `vector<vector<vector<>>>` is the improved version of `int**[n]` rather than the improved version of `int[n][m][o]`.  I advocate flat arrays with n-dimensional adaptors, so you can use `[n][m][o]` for access while there being a flat array at the bottom.

Comment: @Yakk. Ah. I misunderstood your message. I thought that `flat array` meant 1D-array(`int[n]`) .

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it's a syntax error.

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> particleGrid(gridResolution,vector<vector<int>>(gridResolution,vector<int>(10)));
```

Your compiler treat `>>>` in `vector<vector<vector<int>>>` and `>>` in `vector<vector<int>>` as a `>>` operator.
Solution: separate all `>` in this line

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > particleGrid(gridResolution,vector<vector<int> >(gridResolution,vector<int>(10)));
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "Symbol particleGrid is not defined in current scope" error :( Thank you for the suggestion though, Careal!

Comment: @user2158021 oh. I am sorry about that. :( Then it is caused by another problem. I *guess* that `particleGrid` is defined inside a function. (reference: page 18 in http://indico.vecc.gov.in/indico/conferenceDisplay.py/getPic?picId=13&confId=7 ) Have you run the function that define `particleGrid` before calling `particleGrid.clear();` ?

Comment: Well, particleGrid is defined outside my main function along will all my other global variables, so shouldn't that take care of it?

Comment: @user2158021 Are you using `ROOT`? If yes, read `Environment Setup`(page 13-14) in http://root.cern.ch/download/doc/2GettingStarted.pdf .